# Process.domain undefined in Node 0.10

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting around to using domains and am trying a couple of Express domain middleware packages:

https://github.com/brianc/node-domain-middleware
https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain

According to the usage docs on the first one I should have access to `process.domain` but it is undefined.

I am basically doing this in my app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
domains = require('express-domain-middleware');

var app = exports.app = express();
app.use(domains);
```

And in a controller:

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(process.domain);  //undefined
};
```

What gives?

Comment: Well the symbol "process" has to come from somewhere.

Comment: @Pointy `process` is a global variable in Node environment

Comment: @Mohsen well there you go, I was right :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check (using `console.log` or breakpoints) to make sure this line is happening before your `index` method is getting called:

```
express.use(domain);
```

I don't know how your app is structured but order of `app.use` is usually the case.

Your `app.get('/someurl', yourcontroller.index)` should come after `app.use(domain)`.

Comment: That was my thought but I have express.use(domain) as the first middleware after I create app.  The routes are way down the list. I can console.log within the code for the middleware and see that it is being called correctly and before my route.

Comment: You can dig in `express-domain-middleware` and see where it's assigning `proccess.domain`. Don't scare of going inside `node_modules`.

Comment: Figured out it was Mongoose - answer below. process.domain is assigned automatically by node on an active domain. Putting domains on the shelf for now - without Mongoose support its a huge job to recode everything. Will wait till that shows up.

Comment: @Yashua Glad you found the solution. Feel free to pick your own answer as right answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it's due to a Mongo call in my middleware. Evidently all database calls have to be wrapped.

```
var d = domain.create();
d.run(function () {
  client.query('...', d.intercept(function (rows) {
  // ... use rows (note, first arguments error was "intercepted" by the domain)
  }));
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/308